# How to optimize subquery?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and out of which one saves the log of first table.I am using subquery to get data from **log table** but it is taking **.8 seconds** in phpmyadmin.There are more than 2,000 records in Mytable and 7000 in log table.I tried differently but could not find a  way to optimize the query.

**Table structure-**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MyTable` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2182 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `template` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7650 ;
```

**My current working query is-**

```
SELECT a.*,
(select status from log where ID = a.ID AND template="template1" order by timestamp desc limit 1) as template1,
(select status from log where ID = a.ID AND template="template2" order by timestamp desc limit 1) as template2,
(select status from log where ID = a.ID AND template="template3" order by timestamp desc limit 1) as template3                
FROM MyTable a
ORDER BY a.ID DESC
```

**Log table-**

```
uid     ID      template    status  timestamp
7648    2181    template1   P       2014-03-07 05:32:56
7646    2181    template1   R       2014-03-07 05:30:56
7645    2181    template2   R       2014-03-07 05:30:56
7644    2181    template3   R       2014-03-07 05:30:56
7643    2181    template1   R       2014-03-07 05:30:56
7642    2180    template2   R       2014-03-07 05:20:50
7641    2180    template3   p       2014-03-07 05:20:50
7640    2180    template1   R       2014-03-07 05:20:50
```

**MyTable -**

```
ID      Name
2181    test1
2180    test2
2079    test0
```

Comment: a) Tell us what indexes are set. b) Use `EXPLAIN`. c) Next time, include both in your question from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is essentially running 6,000 queries.  For each one record in MyTable, it is running the correlated column-based query from the log table.  What I have proposed here is to pre-query ONCE through the log table pre-grouped by the "ID" column, and getting the maximum "UID" per Log as the respective template ID you want the status from record.  Since the UID is an auto-increment, this would imply that the highest log is the most recent time.

To help optimize this "PreQuery", I would have an index on the  LOG table FOR( template, ID, UID ) another index on the log table by UID is default as it is the primary key.

So, after the prequery is done, I am just creating the JOIN relationships to alternate aliases of the log table based on the respective MAX() ID identified per template. Then, you should be able to get all your details.

IF you think about this one, it is 2 queries being run... the prequery, then the main query which is nothing more than JOINs to the referenced aliases per record

```
SELECT 
      a.*,
      COALESCE( L1.Status, 0 ) as template1,
      COALESCE( L2.Status, 0 ) as template2,
      COALESCE( L3.Status, 0 ) as template3
   FROM 
      MyTable a
      LEFT JOIN
      ( select 
              L.ID,
              MAX( case when L.template = 'template1' then L.UID else 0 end ) as Temp1UID,
              MAX( case when L.template = 'template2' then L.UID else 0 end ) as Temp2UID,
              MAX( case when L.template = 'template3' then L.UID else 0 end ) as Temp3UID
           from
              Log L
           where 
              L.template in ( 'template1', 'template2', 'template' )
           group by
              L.ID
           order by 
              L.ID ) TempByID
         ON a.ID = TempByID.ID
              LEFT JOIN Log L1
                 ON TempByID.Temp1UID = L1.UID
              LEFT JOIN Log L2
                 ON TempByID.Temp2UID = L2.UID
              LEFT JOIN Log L3
                 ON TempByID.Temp3UID = L3.UID
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I checked and it's working fine.But there is an issue if no respective entry in log table it does not display result from mytable.Could you please help me to fix this?

Comment: @Irfan, revised answer for left-join and added COALESCE() to prevent NULLs is no corresponding template.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is:

```
SELECT a.*,
       (select status from log l where l.ID = a.ID AND template="template1" order by timestamp desc limit 1) as template1,
       (select status from log where l.ID = a.ID AND template="template2" order by timestamp desc limit 1) as template2,
       (select status from log where l.ID = a.ID AND template="template3" order by timestamp desc limit 1) as template3                
FROM MyTable a
ORDER BY a.ID DESC   ;
```

For your purposes, probably the most efficient way to get what you want is by creating an index on `log(ID, template, timestamp, status)`:

```
create index log_ID_template_timestamp_status on log(ID, template, timestamp, status)
```

If you want to try another approach, you can try the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` method for fetching the latest or earliest value:

```
select a.*, l.template1, l.template2, l.template3
from MyTable a left outer join
     (select l.id,
             substring_index(group_concat((case when template = 'template1' then status end)
                                          order by timestamp desc
                                         ), ',', 1
                            ) as template1,
             substring_index(group_concat((case when template = 'template2' then status end)
                                          order by timestamp desc
                                         ), ',', 1
                            ) as template2,
             substring_index(group_concat((case when template = 'template3' then status end)
                                          order by timestamp desc
                                         ), ',', 1
                            ) as template3
      from log l
      group by l.id
     ) l
     on a.id = l.id
order by a.id desc;
```